# How would I use the trapezium rule to show this?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How would I go about using the trapezium rule to show
$$\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{c^3}3$$
Given that $x^2$ belongs to the partition $R([0,c])$ and
$$\sum_{i=0}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
I understand partitions but this part isn't covered in the lecture notes and I do not know how to go about solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\triangle X = \frac{c}{n}$

According to the Trapezium rule

$$\int_{0}^{c} x^2 dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{1}^{n} \frac{f(x_{k-1}) + f(x_k)}{2}.\triangle x$$

Further $x_0 = 0$

$x_1 = \frac{c}{n}$

$x_2 = 2\frac{c}{n}$

$x_{k-1} = (k-1)\frac{c}{n}$

$x_k = k\frac{c}{n}$

Substituting  the value of $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$ in to the summation formula, we get

$$\int_{0}^{c} x^2 dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{(k-1)^2c^2}{n^2} + \frac{k^2c^2}{n^2}\right].\frac{c}{n}$$

If you simplify this and use $\sum k^2$ and $\sum k$ in the simplified equation we get

$$\int_{0}^{c} x^2 dx  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{c^3}{2n^3}\left(\frac{2n^3 + n)}{3}\right)$$

$$ = \boxed{\frac{c^3}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By, for example, RRAM approximation,

$$\int_{0}^c x^2\ dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)\left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)^2.$$